# Session cookie set `SameSite=None; Secure;` does not work

Tags: javascript, cookies, samesite, csrf-token

I added SameSite=None; Secure; to set-cookie. but the cookie was not set and I can’t log in to my site.

```
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Set-Cookie': 'token=' + token + '; SameSite=None; Secure; Expires=' + time.toUTCString() + '; Path=/' + '; Domain=' + hostname,
  'csrf-token': csrfToken
});
```

I reviewed the cookie in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details. it showed a warning message:

> this set-cookie was blocked because it was not sent over a secure connection

chrome blockes cookies, Because I work on the development environment and i send http request. But this test on Firefox browser logs in correctly.
I put the word **secure** inside the cookie and it worked properly, but because the word **secure** must be used next to **samesite = none** for **cross-origin**, otherwise the cookie will be blocked.
My question is why when I use **secure**, only the Chrome browser blocks the cookie, but it is true in other browsers.
And that if I do not use **secure** I can not test the payment gateway because it blocks Chrome cross-orign if I do not use secure...

Comment: "_it was not sent over a secure connection_". "_secure connection_" here means https schema, and the cookie is not accepted with http schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question is why when I use secure, only the Chrome browser blocks
> the cookie, but it is true in other browsers

I am not sure about other browsers but Chrome implements strategy of allowing cookies with `secure` attribute over secure connection as per this [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism-00#section-3.2).

While this draft is implemented for Chrome, it is not on Firefox which is why on Firefox in you go to `about:config > network.cookie.sameSite.noneRequiresSecure`, default value is **false**.

If you just need to do it for your local dev environment, You can retain the old behavior for cookies in chrome by **disabling**

1. chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies
2. chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure

> I have to support legacy http clients, but if I make https:// origin
> secure , I can't set cookie from http, more over I can't access this
> cookie from http, my goal is to have SameSite=None, Secure on http and
> not secure on http:// origin, any ideas, instead of establishing
> protests near google office ?

Given that it is going to be standard in near future, I doubt you will be able to achieve this behavior for client applications, only route is to go secure, HTTPS.

Reference:

1. https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/#changes-to-the-default-behavior-without-samesite
2. https://redmondmag.com/articles/2020/01/28/samesite-cookie-changes-break-apps.aspx

Comment: The problem that I can't update clients which uses http, and can't redirect them. The "secure" attribute, makes cookie unusable on http origin, which is wrong i guess, i think it should allow to set separate "non secure" cookie in different storage.

Comment: I'm trying to send cookie cross site via payment gateway using header('Set-Cookie: cookie2=value2; SameSite=None; Secure', true); But once the payment is complete and user gets back to product page to order again, payment is getting done but the cart data (session) is being block by chrome. I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by session is being blocked by chrome. Are you seeing cookie using developer tool? Do you have a site that I can take a look at?

Comment: Support for the `same-site-by-default-cookies` or the other flag on Chrome was removed, so the solution now is to use firefox https://piunikaweb.com/2021/06/14/google-chrome-flags-for-samesite-cookies-taken-away-after-update-v91/

Answer (score 5):

Sometome cookies wouldn't work as expected because Some cookies are misusing the `sameSite` attribute.
Cookie `SomeCookie` rejected cause of it has the `sameSite=none` attribute but it is missing the `secure` attribute. So any cookie that requests `SameSite=None` must marked as `Secure`.

```
Set-Cookie: product=pen; SameSite=None
```

For fixing this, you must add the `Secure` attribute to your `SameSite=None` cookies.

```
Set-Cookie: flavor=choco; SameSite=None; Secure
```

A Secure cookies will only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the `HTTPS` protocol.

**Note:** insecure sites `(http:)` can't set cookies with the `Secure` directive.

Comment: what to do if I just want to make my cookie continue to work in future chromium releases the same way as before (regardless secure, be crossdomain) ?

Comment: I think the official answer to your follow up question is "get the clients off HTTP", they *really* don't want to keep supporting non-SSL connections

Comment: thanks for the **Note**. Any way though of making this work with http:<IP>:<PORT> on development?

Comment: but i dont have https for my local development setup, how am I supposed to set a cookie if setting a cookie cross-site requires `SameSite=None` and `SameSite=None` requires `Secure=true`, this is ridiculous